# Wordpress website rel in attribute in html 5

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slider, validation

I am using a validator.w3 and I get this kind of error:
`Bad value 1 for attribute rel on element a: The string 1 is not a registered keyword.`

when I tried deleting or change the rel attribute the slider in which the id controller located will not work.I dont know what I'm suppose to do with this.. what value should I change?..This site is in html 5.Please help

```
<div id="controllers">
<a href="#" id="left-arrow">Previous</a>
<a href="#" rel="1" class="switch active">1</a>
<a href="#" rel="2" class="switch">2</a>
<a href="#" rel="3" class="switch">3</a>
<a href="#" id="right-arrow">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rel` attribute has a limited (though large) set of values in HTML5. The set can be extended via the [existing rel values](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values) wiki. However, it is practically certain that values like 1, 2, 3 would not be approved, as they are nonsensical in a global context.

If the software you use needs them, keep using them. If this results in an inconveniently large number of error messages, making it difficult to study other error messages, use the http://validator.w3.org/nu/ version of the validator. It lets you filter out selecter types of errors.

Comment: the problem was solve, change the rel into id so it became <a href="#" id="1" class="switch active">1</a>